# STM32 PWM output duty cycle is not accurate

Tags: stm32, pwm, duty-cycle

I am using an STM32f051C8T6 and I am trying to control the PWM duty cycle, however, the duty cycle is inaccurate. I set it to be 50%, but the output is less than 40%. Also, the frequency is wrong; I used the internal clock, which is 8 MHz, and the counter set up to 512. I expected the frequency of the PWM would be 8,000,000/512 = 15.6 kHz, but it is 93.4kHz; it is way off.

Can anyone help me and figure out what I did wrong?

```
 /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 1 */
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 511;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 255;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Tip: there's a `{}` button for formatting code. Use the preview before submitting your post. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Do you mean STM32f**4**051C8T6?

Comment: No, it is STM32f051C8T6